# Registered user not showing in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In short, I want my Authenticated user by Email and Password in firebase firestore,
After successfully register my users only appears in a **authentication** pannel.
I am currently working with Flutter application where I use `firebase_auth: ^1.1.1` package.
So I expect that after

```
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "abc@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
```

The function called from firebase_auth package which is **createUserWithEmailAndPassword**
I want this registed user in Firebase Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase authentication is used to register a user while firestore is used for storing data. If you want to add the user to firestore also then you need to add the `cloud_firestore` plugin to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
```

Then you can do:

```
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set(
  {
    "email" : "abc@example.com",
  }).then((_){
    print("success!");
  });
```

This will create a collection called `users` with a document id equal to the authenticated user id, and inside of it you will have the email of the user.

Answer (score 2):

`.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`  creates a user in auth, if you check your auth tab you should see created user. **It does not  create user in firestore**
for this you have to implement  yourself .

below is a sample example

```
         final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
          User user = (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password))
            .user;
        //if create user succeeds
var user =UserModel( 
userID:user.uid,
email:user.email)
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
    //save user based on their id from auth
    
                    .doc("users/${user.uid}")
                    .set(user.toJson());
```

**Edit**

you can create a user model
example:

```
class UserModel {
  final String userID;
  final String displayName;
  final String email, pushToken;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String profilePictureURL, dateJoined;

  UserModel({
   
    this.dateJoined,
    this.userID,
 
    this.email,
   
  });

  Map<String, Object> toJson() {
    return {
      
     
      'userID': userID,
      
      'email': email == null ? '' : email,
      
      'appIdentifier': 'my app',
      'dateJoined': DateTime.now(),
    };
  }
}
....
```

check how to use [json](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: Where did **toJson()** come from

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [griffins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67320717/6767981), you could use a [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) to respond to the user creation event ([trigger onCreated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)). Then you can create the users collection, asynchronously, without overloading the flutter client. For example, an `index.ts` with the `createUserInFirestore` function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

export const createUserInFirestore = functions.auth.user().onCreate(
    async (user) => {
        return db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
            "email" : user.email,
            "name" : user.displayName,
        });
    }
);
```