# Writing firstore Error. There is an account in Authentication, But there is no userdata in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

After i finish the form and click 'Sign up'
there is an error.

The account was successfully made in Firebase Console -Authentication.
But There isn't any date in Firebase Console-FireStore.
There should be user date.

I got a error message 'Couldn't sign up'.

below is my code.

Click Sign up button, then this function will run

```
_signUpWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    await showProgress(
        context, 'Creating new account, Please wait...'.tr(), false);
    dynamic result = await FireStoreUtils.firebaseSignUpWithEmailAndPassword(
        email!.trim(),
        password!.trim(),
        _image,
        firstName!,
        lastName!,
        mobile!);
    await hideProgress();
    if (result != null && result is User) {
      MyAppState.currentUser = result;
      pushAndRemoveUntil(context, ContainerScreen(user: result), false);
    } else if (result != null && result is String) {
      showAlertDialog(context, 'Failed'.tr(), result, true);
    } else {
      showAlertDialog(context, 'Failed'.tr(), 'Couldn\'t sign up'.tr(), true);
    }
  }
```

To take the result, this function below will run.

FireStoreUtils.firebaseSignUpWithEmailAndPassword

```
 static firebaseSignUpWithEmailAndPassword(
      String emailAddress,
      String password,
      File? image,
      String firstName,
      String lastName,
      String mobile) async {
    try {
      auth.UserCredential result = await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: emailAddress, password: password);
      String profilePicUrl = '';
      if (image != null) {
        updateProgress('Uploading image, Please wait...'.tr());
        profilePicUrl =
            await uploadUserImageToFireStorage(image, result.user?.uid ?? '');
      }
      User user = User(
          email: emailAddress,
          settings: UserSettings(),
          photos: [],
          lastOnlineTimestamp: Timestamp.now(),
          active: true,
          phoneNumber: mobile,
          firstName: firstName,
          userID: result.user?.uid ?? '',
          lastName: lastName,
          fcmToken: await firebaseMessaging.getToken() ?? '',
          profilePictureURL: profilePicUrl);
      String? errorMessage = await firebaseCreateNewUser(user);
      if (errorMessage == null) {
        return user;
      } else {
        return 'Couldn\'t sign up for firebase, Please try again.';
      }
    } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      print(error.toString() + '${error.stackTrace}');
      String message = 'Couldn\'t sign up';
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'email-already-in-use':
          message = 'Email already in use, Please pick another email!';
          break;
        case 'invalid-email':
          message = 'Enter valid e-mail';
          break;
        case 'operation-not-allowed':
          message = 'Email/password accounts are not enabled';
          break;
        case 'weak-password':
          message = 'Password must be more than 5 characters';
          break;
        case 'too-many-requests':
          message = 'Too many requests, Please try again later.';
          break;
      }
      return message;
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Couldn\'t sign up';
    }
  }
```

After make FirebaseAuth,
It should make User date in firestore. with below funtion.

```
  static Future<String?> firebaseCreateNewUser(User user) async =>
      await firestore
          .collection(USERS)
          .doc(user.userID)
          .set(user.toJson())
          .then((value) => null, onError: (e) => e);
```

The app say's
"Could't sign up"
And there is an account in Authentication, But there is no userdata in firestore.

My pubspec is below.

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  firebase_core: ^1.0.4
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.6
```

Thank you for your help.

```
D/InputMethodManager(16995): HSIFW - flag : 0
W/System  (16995): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(16995): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(16995): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System  (16995): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(16995): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(16995): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/FirebaseAuth(16995): Notifying id token listeners about user ( OkuuQUS2NETsO5ZZtsE8cgb4QFl2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(16995): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( OkuuQUS2NETsO5ZZtsE8cgb4QFl2 ).
```

I added an error message above.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67320717/10409567

Comment: Could you print the error in the last catch block and update the answer with the error message/stacktrace to help identify the error?

Comment: I added it! thanks for your help
@VictorEronmosele

Comment: Did you add `print(e);` before `return 'Couldn\'t sign up';` so it prints the error message? The added console messages are not showing enough information.